# LinearLayout pushing TextView out of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm fairly new to Android app development and I have run into a bit of a problem.

I have a LinearLayout with 2 ImageButtons in it and another LinearLayout with a TextView on the top as you can see here -

[Looks pretty-ish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXvsV.png)

However, I have tried to add another LinearLayout to add more things into, but it starts to push my Welcome message out of the screen

[I add another LinearLayout and this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYkTR.png)

Here's the XML for the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_weight="0.6"
          android:id="@+id/layout_home">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:longClickable="false">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Welcome"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textSize="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="#5cfca1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/whatisit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="300dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/howcanitreatit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Edited: Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>
```

I've looked at other questions but they've seemed to do a lot different in terms of setting out their layout and have a lot more elements and such.

Why is it pushing the welcome message out? What am I doing wrong here?

Also feel free to scrutinise anything. The more mistakes I've done, the better

Comment: why adding layout weight?

Comment: Post `style.xml` file.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir the layout_weight on the ImageButtons is to split them. Anything else is probably a mistake from experimenting

Comment: @dieter_h Edited, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this portion of code (2nd `LinearLayout`):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        >
```

Take out : `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Also remove : `android:paddingBottom="300dp"` from the last `LinearLayout`

That will make it show, however you are using hard coded `dp` values a lot, this is never really good practice as you have to cater for lots of different screen sizes.

Comment: Amazing! It did fix it. Thank you very much. I'm working on the hard coded values, someone's already mentioned that and I'm editing as we speak

Comment: Either/Both suggestions fix the problem - your'e hard coded `dp` values were pushing the contents beyond the screen boundary - it simply didn't fit

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
        android:longClickable="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="#5cfca1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/whatisit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="300dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/howcanitreatit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this didn't make a difference (Still has the same result)

Answer (score 0):

The android_height and android_width properties are there to tell the screen how to render, your welcome msg have a fill_parent propert which basically tells it it should spread all over the screen, change it to wrap content, either way as for now the heights and widths you gave it is probabley larger then the screen size and also a BAD HABIT since it will not match the 7300+ different android phones out there, as a thumb rule you should keep those sizes in xml.
to read more about that please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article

Comment: This is what most tutorials don't tell you. Thank you very much for this advice! Will take a look at this page and edit shortly

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a **fixed** height for the **Welcome** `TextView` if that is possible with your requirement.

E.g: `android:layout_height="65dp"`

Comment: Hello there and thank you for responding! Unfortunately, it still has the same outcome: https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/ced0966c2ba69294afab0839f80e6d40.png

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following LOC from the second `LinearLayout`. ie: The `LinearLayout` just after the `ScrollView`.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```